# How to interpret wolfram rule 108 as a simplified populationmodel

Tags: cellular-automata

I have made a Matlab-program as to iterate wolfram-rule 108 on any chosen begin situation. However my question is how this rule can be interpreted as a simplified version of a population model.

(some graphs for rule 108 can be found here : http://atlas.wolfram.com/01/01/108/)

Comment: Do you have a pointer to any post or literature indicating the Rule 108 can be used as a population growth model? A quick experiment running Rule 108 from all possible 3-tuples indicates that it is [class 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton#Classification), i.e. it displays periodic patterns that remain localized.  I don't see how to use this to model a population - unless that population remains stable.

Comment: I indeed tought of it as a class 2 type of rule either but in the excercise the professor said the following :"Rule 108 can be interpreted as a very simple population dynamics
model. Explain."

Comment: The only answer I see is that in a way... the population is a bit 'self-regulating' as in... "when tere are too many bunnies some die and when there is room for more , more births generally happen" . It's just a stupid example but in that way it might be both class 2 AND a very VERY basic populationdynamics model .. where 2 times positive next to each other is the boundary for this specific population.. Making one (the middle one) die out if the boundary is reached.  Does this make any sense at all?